# Merge multiple time columns into a single column using wide_to_long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has multiple time columns and an assigned value.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {0: 0.2, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.4, 3: nan}, 'val1': {0: 1.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 1.0, 3: nan}, 'time2': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.8, 3: 1.0}, 'val2': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 9, 3: 2}})
```

Which looks like this:

```
   time  val1  time2  val2
0   0.2   1.0    0.1     2
1   0.3   3.0    0.4     2
2   0.4   1.0    0.8     9
3   NaN   NaN    1.0     2
```

There can be many more time and value columns (but they always come in pairs). I would like to merge all the times columns into ONE column, while keeping and filling in the `val`'s to their corressponding times.

Example output:

```
   time  val1   val2
0   0.1   1.0    2.0     
1   0.2   1.0    2.0     
2   0.3   3.0    2.0     
3   0.4   1.0    2.0   
4   0.8   1.0    9.0   
5   1.0   1.0    2.0
```

I have asked this question previously, and one answer got very close! Answer and output below:

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns={'time':'time1'}).reset_index(),
                      'time', i='index', j='t')
        .sort_values(['time','val2'])
        .drop_duplicates('time')
        .dropna(subset=['time'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output:

```
   val1  val2  time
0   1.0     2   0.1
1   1.0     2   0.2
2   3.0     2   0.3
3   3.0     2   0.4 <- val1 incorrect
4   1.0     9   0.8
5   NaN     2   1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can't achieve this with `wide_to_long`.

You don't have a canonical reshaping. There are duplicate values (e.g. time 0.4) and you need to make a choice here.

So, I guess you need to perform two merges and combine in the desired order:

```
m1 = (
 df[['time', 'val1']]
 .merge(df[['time2', 'val2']]
        .rename(columns={'time2': 'time'}),
        on='time', how='outer')
 .sort_values(by='time')
)

m2 = (
 df[['time', 'val2']]
 .merge(df[['time2', 'val1']]
        .rename(columns={'time2': 'time'}),
        on='time', how='outer')
 .sort_values(by='time')
)

out = m1.combine_first(m2).dropna(subset='time')
```

output:

```
   time  val1  val2
4   0.1   1.0   2.0
0   0.2   1.0   2.0
1   0.3   3.0   2.0
2   0.4   1.0   2.0
5   0.8   1.0   9.0
6   1.0   NaN   2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another simple approach. `melt` the data, sort to have time1 before time2 and in case of duplicate times, get the first row for val1 and last for val2.

```
cols = ['val1', 'val2']
(df
 .rename(columns={'time': 'time1'})
 .melt(id_vars=cols, value_name='time')
 .dropna(subset='time')
 .sort_values(by=['time', 'variable'])
 .groupby('time').agg({'val1': 'first', 'val2': 'last'})
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   time  val1  val2
0   0.1   1.0     2
1   0.2   1.0     2
2   0.3   3.0     2
3   0.4   1.0     2
4   0.8   1.0     9
5   1.0   NaN     2
```